# Sprite Kit how to update an image on a button?

Tags: swift, storyboard, sprite-kit, xcode-storyboard

I am new to Swift and Sprite Kit.

I want in MyScene.swift to create a button that has a specific image. Every time I click on the button I want to change the button image with a new image.
How can I do that?

```
GameScene.swift

class GameScene: SKScene {
var rollButton:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dice1.png")

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

 rollButton.position = CGPoint(x: 79, y: 290) //this position is based to what? Is there an easier way to put a button using storyborard

  rollButton.setScale(0.5) //what does setScale mean?
self.addChild(rollButton)
}

 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
  for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    if CGRectContainsPoint(rollButton.frame, touch.locationInNode(self)) {
      changeButtonImage()
    }
   }
 }

func changeButtonImage() {
//radom get value beteween 1 - 6
change the rollButton image with a new value??? //how to do that
}
```

1. Is there a way i an add a UIButton on Storyboard and than connect
   GameScene,swift with that storyboard? (adding child nodes
   programatically can be really hard)
2. The CGPoint of a node is based to what? the current UIView?
3. How to programatically change the image of a button (in swift using
   SpriteKit Node) with other images if for example I have the images:
   dice1, dice2, dice3...

This is the objective C code:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dice%d.png", num];
// Setting the uiimageview to the appropriate image
self.rollButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
```

I didn't find any good example with how to set buttons from storyborard and than using uiviewcontrollers to each new GameScene created,

Answer (score 3):

First, create an array of the images you want the button to have:

```
let arrayOfImages = [
  "image1.png",
  "image2.png",
  "image3.png",
  "image4.png",
  "image5.png",
  "image6.png"
]
```

Then initialize the button sprite and give it a texture to start:

```
var rollButton = SKSpriteNode()
rollButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: arrayOfImages[0])
```

Then, each time `changeButtonImage()` is called, generate a random number and change the button's texture:

```
var randomNumberBetween0And5 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
rollButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: arrayOfImages[randomNumberBetween0And5])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a button or a switch for generic use, you should try this control I made, the use its pretty straight forward:
You just initialize the type of Button/Switch you want (ColoredSprite, Textured or TextOnly)

```
let control = TWButton(normalColor: SKColor.blueColor(), highlightedColor: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 160, height: 80))
```

And after initialize you add a closure to it (like addTargetForSelector on UIButton)

```
 control.addClosureFor(.TouchUpInside, target: self, closure: { (scene, sender) -> () in
            scene.testProperty = "Changed Property"
        })
    }
```

That’s it! There’s more info on the readme section on the GitHub page: https://github.com/txaidw/TWControls

But if you want to implement in a specific node here’s how I did:

```
internal override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)

    if self.containsPoint(touchPoint) {
        self.touchLocationLast = touchPoint
        touchDown()
    }
}

internal override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)
    self.touchLocationLast = touchPoint
}


internal override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchPoint = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)

        if let lastPoint = self.touchLocationLast where self.containsPoint(lastPoint) {
            // Ended inside
            touchUpInside()
        }
        else {
            // Ended outside
            touchUpOutside()
        }
}
```